# Angular 17 componentes standalone y problema con routerLink

Tags: angular, routerlink, standalone

No consigo que me funcione routelink en Angular 17.

En un componente defino:

```js
     import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
     ...
 
     @Component({
       selector: 'app-header',
       standalone: true,
       imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, TranslateModule],
       templateUrl: './app.component.html',
       styleUrl: './app.component.css',
     })
     export class AppComponent {
 
       constructor(
         private readonly router: Router,
         private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
         
     ...
```

```
Y en el html:
```

```html
    <li [routerLink]="['/empresa']">
      EMPRESA
    </li>
```

Que puede ser lo que estoy haciendo mal?.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas agregar la importación directamente:

```
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
```

Y luego en las importaciones de tu componente standalone.

[Más detalles.](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)